# how to remove double inverted commas when calling php row value on javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Please help, This is what I am using.

```
$('#upload-image-form<?php echo json_encode($row['id']); ?>).on('submit', function(e) {some javascript code};
```

This is what I am getting(view page source)

```
$('#upload-image-form"475").on('submit', function(e) {some javascript code}
```

And this is what I want(view page source)

```
$('#upload-image-form475).on('submit', function(e) {some javascript code}
```

Comment: this is what i am using: $('#upload-image-form<?php echo json_encode($row['id']); ?>).on('submit', function(e) {

Comment: Don't json encode the row id. Just do: `<?php echo $row['id']; ?>`

Comment: Why are you using `json_encode` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of `json_encode()`here.

Just Change :-

```
$('#upload-image-form<?php echo json_encode($row['id']); ?>)
```

to

```
$('#upload-image-form<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>')
```

***Note:-*** You missed single quote in end in your original code

Comment: @FhumulaniMabaso  glad to help you :):)